# How to fix casting error with Cast in C#?

Tags: c#, casting

```
SystemIO[] s = Enum.GetNames(typeof(SystemIO)).Cast<SystemIO>().ToArray();
```

I want to cast my `string[]` to `SystemIO[]`.

I get the following error:

> Trace: at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__97`1.MoveNext()
>   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>   at TestCase.TestCaseGeneral.AllIos()

Why cant I cast in this way?

Comment: Did you meant to use `GetValues`, rather than `GetNames`? `GetNames` returns a list of the string names of the enum members, and a string can't just be cast to an enum.

Comment: In general the exception message will give you more detail and a basis for doing some googling.

Comment: When posting error information, please include the exception type and message as well. Currently you've only posted the stack trace, which might indicate something but is not as good as the exception type and message.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to obtain *values* put `Enum.GetValues`:

```
SystemIO[] s = Enum
  .GetValues(typeof(SystemIO))
  .Cast<SystemIO>()
  .ToArray();
```

If you want *names* change `s` type (names are `string`s):

```
string[] s = Enum
  .GetNames(typeof(SystemIO));
```